# Install Ubuntu 13-10 in German

Tags: language-support

I have downloaded UBUNTU 13.10 32 Bit version and installed it. I would like to have it in the German language but dont't know how to change the language. Prior to that I had the 64 Bit version in German installed, but had to uninstall it because the computer ist too slow. If there is no other way, I can use it in English too, but it would be more comfortable for me to use the German language.
Thank for any help!
Bringfried

Comment: Switching languages is done in System Settings. You may need to install the German language support (which can be done from there). Then, press "apply to the entire system".

Comment: Also, it is always possible to install Ubuntu in German. It ships with all necessary language packages preinstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your control center:

```
gnome-control-center &
```

Find the *Language Support* tool (under Personal settings).

[image]

Click on <kbd>Install/Remove Languages...</kbd>. Find German and select it.

[image]

Click <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd>

After the procedure you will be able to select German as the primary language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did as you suggested, but to no avail. Just like in you first screen shot, I have the various English versions and German. When I try to pull the German language above the English, it alway jumps back again. Then removed English completely. With only the German language there, I clicked "Apply System-wide". Yet I still have only English, even after a new start of the system. I don't know any more what to do.

Comment: If you pull German above the very first English alternative, it should stay there and become the default language after re-log in.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the language packs?

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-de
sudo apt-get install language-pack-de-base
```

After that you should be able to change the language in the options
(unity menu, search for "language")

Comment: Better to use the GUI. It installs the necessary packages as well as generates the locales.

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. I know my way around Windows, but what you write is Chineese to me. I guess those are terminal commands, but how to I get into terminal mode on Ubuntu?